# H2 : Column not found when name has number in it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I have a column in my database table named '1GNics'. I can create the table in H2 using the following SQL

```
CREATE TABLE resource( ... 1GNics int DEFAULT NULL, ... );
```

This creates the table with the correct column name but if i try do a select it takes the select statement as follows and tries to select the top 1 from the table

```
SELECT 1 GNics from RESOURCE;
```

Even do the select statement reads

```
SELECT 1GNics from RESOURCE;
```

I am using hibernate to access the database so it is generating the select statements automatically. Is there a way of selecting this without changing the column name to 'oneGNics' ?

Comment: Did you try surrounding the column name with quotes: `SELECT "1GNics" from RESOURCE;` or single quotes `SELECT '1GNics' from RESOURCE;`?

Comment: Yes i have tried this and it works, but the problem is that hibernate is generating the SQL select statements in my code so it will not generate a select statement with the column name as "1GNics", it does not add in the quotationg marks

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't notice the autogeneration of the query. Might be that you need to work around this by writing native/HQL queries by hand if you cannot change the column name. This actually seems like a bug in Hibernate and/or the H2 driver. The column name looks like valid ANSI-SQL.

Comment: Okay, looking more closely at the [H2 grammar guide](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#name), it seems that column names have to start with `A-Z` (case-insensitive), unless they're [quoted](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#quoted_name) when you create the table. So, you basically have an invalid column identifier there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HQL` and use query as follows

```
session.createQuery("SELECT \"1GNics\" from RESOURCE");
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the query:

`SELECT r.1GNics from RESOURCE AS r;`

You can use alias of `Table`.

Comment: Hibernate uses aliases when it is generates its statements so this does not work

Comment: You can try with SELECT `1GNics` from RESOURCE; query as well. I am not able to show sign as SO is using it as code identifier.